# Need to remove date string on file

Tags: shell, powershell, command

Need some help creating a script to remove the date string and "backup" added when SQL server does a backup.

The format is: `DatabaseName_backup_2016_10_24_010000_6215942`.

Started with:

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\temp\Backup\ -include *.bak
```

Going to start looking into options but also looking for insight. Open to using other scripts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
gci c:\temp\backup\*.bak | ren -N { $_ -replace 'backup_\d+_\d+_\d+_' } -whatif
# get matching files and | rename them with new names
# replacement pattern is 'backup' followed by strings of digits and underscores, replaced with nothing.
```

`-whatif` means it won't actually make any changes, just tell you what it would do.

---

**Help Links** (if available):

- gci is an alias for [`Get-ChildItem`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management)
- ren is an alias for [`Rename-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113382) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management)

Comment: I was about to edit to expand the aliases ... but it would ruin your perfect design.

Answer (score 0):

You can regular expressions for example:

```
$old = "DatabaseName_backup_2016_10_24_010000_6215942.bak"

$old -replace "([^_]+_)(backup_\d+_\d+_\d+_)(\d+_\d+\.bak)","`$1`$3"

#Result : DatabaseName_010000_6215942.bak
```

More information here: https://powershell.org/2013/08/29/regular-expressions-are-a-replaces-best-friend/

Answer (score 0):

After playing around this worked. The `-whatif` switch will need to be removed for it to work. I renamed all the SQL backups in the folder:

```
gci C:\SQL_backup\*.bak | ren -N { $_ -replace '_backup_\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+' } -whatif
```

Comment: sorry for the delay.  I'm the only System admin onsite